# rsync partial file naming

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, rsync

In my scenario, I use `rsync` to backup some files over network and from USB drives to a folder. Then use `aws s3 mv` to send it to cloud storage in a continous loop; when it finishes, it look again for new files on this folder.

I'm thinking about making this process "safe". When `rsync` is copying a file to folder I don't want `aws s3 mv` to store a partial file, but if that file is complete, no problem, even if the whole folder are not in sync.

I couldn't find rsync partial file naming rules. Seems something like `name.extension.randomcode`. I'm wondering to use `aws s3 mv` with `--exclude=*.part`, but rsync doesn't use a simple name like this.

How is the rsync partial file naming rule? Any other suggestions to filter?

Comment: rsync most likely uses `mktemp(3)`, see that manual page for naming scheme.

Comment: There is some useful advice in this thread about temporary files you may find useful if not already considered. https://superuser.com/questions/579001/rsync-does-it-create-a-temp-file-during-transfer

Answer (score 1):

If I use `rsync --partial-dir=DIR` it only move partials to this folder if the process is interrupted.
So I used `-T, --temp-dir=DIR` in a folder in same drive but outside the folder that is sent to cloud. So there is no way to send a partial file to cloud.